# Implementing x86 Intel 32bit assembly compare function

Tags: x86, intel

I've been trying to convert this C function into assembly. The issue is I don't know if I am doing this right. This is my first time, and I wanted to know from you guys how I am doing + some advice. Thank you!

C code:

```
 unsigned int max(unsigned int a, unsigned int b){
    //computes the max of a and b
   return a > b ? a : b;
     }
```

Assembly:

```
.global max 
.global knapsack
.equ wordsize, 4

.text

.data



max:
  push %ebp
  movl %esp, %ebp
  mov %eax, 4(%esp)
  mov %ebx, 8(%esp)
  cmp %ebx, %eax
  jg knapsack
  cmp %eax, %ebx
  jg knapsack
  movl %ebp, %esp 
  ret 

 knapsack:

    *Working on this function
```

Comment: If `a > b` then you don't have to check `b > a` next. Uh, just as in the C source really. You forgot the update the result - but perhaps that is due to the `knapsack` reference, as it is not present in the C source at all. If this was intended as a stand-alone function, don't jump into the next one at will.